Sinking and sourcing current from and to the output of the op-amp
I need to have a set-up to sink and source current from the output of an op-amp to measure the maximum output current of an op-amp. This is the test set-up I thought of:
If the maximum output swing is known, a slow ramp with maximum swing is applied to the input of the op-amp. There are also some resistors at the output which are paralleled one by one to increase the output current and output voltage swing is monitored via the ADC. when I see an output voltage clipping, that divided by the load resistance is the maximum output current.

This method doesn't create a good estimation because the number of resistors at the output are limited and paralleling them needs a lot of switches and digital IOs.
So, the question is what is a better and continuous method to sink and source current from the op-amp output?

How precisely do you want to be able to set the load resistance? If your resistors had a binary sequence of values (1, 2, 4, 8 ohms, for example) you could adjust the load over a wide range with a minimum number of switches and control signals.

You can use an opamp plus an external transistor and a shunt resistor to create a precision, voltage-controlled current sink or source.  With the input to the opamps coming from D/A converters, you have computer control of the current load.
Here is an article on the subject.
https://blog.mbedded.ninja/electronics/components/current-sources-and-sinks/

You don't say what your resistor coding scheme is, but this from your question

some resistors at the output which are paralleled one by one

implies that they are equal, which rather limits the range of loads you can apply.
If you choose your resistors in a binary sequence, 1, 2, 4, 8 etc, then you rapidly get a wide and finely-settable range as you add more switches and resistors.
